# unpack return function arguments with *args

Tags: python, function, args

Looking for some guidance on how I can properly unpack return arguments in other functions using *args? This is the code;

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

def func1():

    test1 = 'hello'
    test2 = 'hey'

    return test1, test2


def func2(*args):

    print args[0]
    print args[1]

func2(func1)
```

The error message I'm getting;

```
    <function func1 at 0x7fde3229a938>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "args_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    func2(func1)
  File "args_test.py", line 17, in func2
    print args[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I've tried a few things like `args()` but with no success. What am I doing wrong when trying to unpack?

Comment: Try `func2(func1())`

Comment: You mean `func2(*func1())` @DipakChandranP :)

Comment: @Bahrom No, just with out `*`, like : `func2(func1())`

Comment: That won't work, you'll still give it a single tuple which it will interpret to be the only argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't call `func`, so your `func2` is actually getting a single argument, which is a function object. Change your code to: `func2(*func1())`

```
# While you're at it, also unpack the results so hello and hey are interpreted as 2 separate string arguments, and not a single tuple argument 
>>> func2(*func1())
hello
hey

>>> func2(func1)
<function func1 at 0x11548AF0>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    func2(func1)
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 4, in func2
    print args[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

For reference:

```
>>> func1
<function func1 at 0x11548AF0>
>>> func1()
('hello', 'hey')
>>>
```

Comment: `func2(*func1())` : Can you please explain how exactly this statement works? `*` on this!!!

Comment: `*` is the unpacking operator that unpacks the tuple output of `func1()` into two arguments. Suppose `func1` returns `(1, 2)` If you just do `func2(func1())`, you are actually calling `func2((1, 2))` (note there's only one argument, which happens to be a tuple of two elements). Calling `func2(*(1, 2))` unpacks that tuple into two arguments, resulting in `func2(1, 2)`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. like this right:
`>>> f2(f1())`
`((2, 4),)`
`>>> f2(*f1())`
`(2, 4)`

Comment: Yes, in one case you have `f((2, 4),)`, and in the unpacked version you have `f(2, 4)`

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

func2 takes multiple arguments and you specified only one in your code
You can easily see if by printing all the `args`. You can also see, that it fails to print `args[1]` not `args[0]`, because you have passed one argument to that function.